# Instantiate a case class with Options and Scala Enumeration in Java

Tags: java, scala, enumeration, case-class, scala-option

It seems like if a case class has both enums and options, I cannot instantiate it from Java.

Consider the following in Scala:

```
object WeekDay extends Enumeration {
    type WeekDay = Value
    val Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri, Sat, Sun = Value
  }
case class EnumOption(e: WeekDay.Value, s: Option[String])
case class EnumOnly  (e: WeekDay.Value, s: String)
case class OptionOnly(e: Int, s: Option[String])
```

And the following in Java to use them:

```
scala.Enumeration.Value monday = WeekDay.Mon();
EnumOption a = new EnumOption(monday, Option.apply("12"));
EnumOnly b = new EnumOnly(monday, "12");
OptionOnly c = new OptionOnly(12, Option.apply("12"));
```

I get an error (at least Eclipse shows me an error) on instantiating `a` but `b` and `c` work just fine! Any idea how I can instantiate `EnumOption` in Java???

Comment: Is this a bug in scala compiler? (or maybe just a bug in Eclipse??)

Comment: The error is that no constructor with that signature can be found. I will add the exact message to the question.

Comment: I see no error with IntelliJ. What versions of Java, Scala are you using?

Comment: I am getting crazy. Now I see no error either! So it was just an eclipse bug, and it is not reproducible! :( So much for the time I wasted on fixing it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: Now the same code gives me no error. So it was an eclipse bug, and it is not reproducible!

---

Disclaimer: This is only a workaround that I have currently opted for.

```
case class EnumOption(e: WeekDay.Value, s: Option[String])
object EnumOption {
  def optionAvailable(e: WeekDay.Value, s: String) = new EnumOption(e, Some(s))
  def notAvailable(e: WeekDay.Value) = new EnumOption(e, None)
}
```

and then use either of the two methods above.

Clearly this is not a viable solution if there are many `Option`s around and the combinations would grow radically. But for my case (the real application) I had three combinations. Of course, I hope there will be a better solution.